# Changing color of the Status bar with colorPrimaryDark is not working

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-appcompat

SO, I'm trying to change the color of the status bar, but for some reason, it's not working. My API level is 29. None of the colors from the color.xml file work. Here's my code:

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="tab_text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/cerebrisans_medium</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#03A9F4</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
</resources>
```

When I change from .DarkActionBar to .noActionBar I get error in my splash screen activity. Line: "getSupportActionBar().hide();"

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen_);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        statusBarColor();


private void statusBarColor() {
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                Window window = getWindow();
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yellow));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is the parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" ?
If the user's phone is set to a different theme on their phone, then this theme might not be getting called.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to answer that. Why would Google make it if we shouldn't use it?

Comment: It's not that you shouldn't use it.
The theme is taken from the system, meaning that if you extend the Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar, it will only appear on your application if the user has set the device system theme to Light \ Dark Action Bar.
In other words, if the user has his device system theme set to Dark theme, your implementation will not be called by the system.
You should extend all possible variations and implement them accordingly, or extend a general theme.